# Type error for params of sdl_CreateWindow using PySdl2

Tags: python, pyopengl, pysdl2

The following code fragment:

```
self.width = 640
self.height = 400

self.window = sdl2.SDL_CreateWindow (
    'OpenGL test',
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    self.width,
    self.height,
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
)
```

gives this error on Windows:

[image]

Seems there's something wrong with this parameter:

```
sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
```

Using:

- Python 3.5
- PySDL2 0.9.5

Strange thing is this used to work on Python 2.7.

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the (beep) unicode thing. Correct code:

```
self.width = 640
self.height = 400

self.window = sdl2.SDL_CreateWindow (
    b'OpenGL test',     #!!!!!!! Note the b !!!!!!!
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    self.width,
    self.height,
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | sdl2.SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
)
```

And the error message showed the wrong line, which doesn't help.